# Array not populating in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, php-7.2

I am populating an `array` `$du` through a `foreach` loop like this

```
foreach ( $arr as $v => $r ) {
            $du['id'] = $r['id'];
            $du['name'] = $r['name'];
            $Sales->insert($du);
            $du = '';
   }
```

The above piece of code is populating `$du` properly in `PHP 5.6` and `PHP 7.0.2` but when we upgraded to `PHP 7.2` `$du` is returning 1.

Comment: Did you define the array in advance? `$du = array();`? Also, why do you have `$du = '';`? You reset `$du` on every iteration.

Comment: _“$du is returning 1”_ - what do you even mean by that? There is no return statement anywhere in the code you have shown. Are you actually talking about the return value of the method call `$Sales->insert($du);`, or what?

Comment: What do you mean with **return 1**? Is this code in a function or method? Where does it get called? Please post the full code.

Comment: By returning I mean when I `print_r` `$du` it returns 1.

Comment: @misorude yes I mean return value of the method call.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment resetting `$du` works.

```
foreach ( $arr as $v => $r ) {
            $du['id'] = $r['id'];
            $du['name'] = $r['name'];
            $Sales->insert($du);
            $du = [];
   }
```